# How to expand buttons and labels to fill the x axis in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a part of code from my school project.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font

class student_window():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.student_win = master
        #window = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.student_win.geometry("1280x720")
        self.header1Font = Font(family='Helvetica', size=20)
        self.optionFont = Font(family='Sans Serrif', size=20)
        self.student_win.focus()
        self.show_window()


    def show_window(self):
        print("ookk")
        self.student_win.title("Student Window")
        self.option_frame = Frame(self.student_win, width=200, height=720)
        lbl_header = Label(self.option_frame,text="EXAMINATION", font=self.header1Font, fg='white', bg='#172D44').grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        lbl_welcome = Label(self.option_frame, text="Welcome,", fg='#E9F1F7', bg='#2A3F54').grid(row=1,column=0)
        lbl_username = Label(self.option_frame, text="Username", fg='white', bg='#2A3F54').grid(row=2,column=0)
        lbl_header2 = Label(self.option_frame, text="STUDENT CORNER", fg='white', bg='#2A3F54').grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.btn_tests = Button(self.option_frame, text="Attempt Exam", fg='#E9F1F7', bg='#35495D', relief=FLAT)
        self.btn_tests.grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.btn_attempts = Button(self.option_frame, text="Attempts", fg='#E9F1F7', bg='#2A3F54', relief=FLAT)
        self.btn_attempts.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.btn_result = Button(self.option_frame, text="Result", fg='#E9F1F7', bg='#2A3F54', relief=FLAT)
        self.btn_result.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.btn_goBack = Button(self.option_frame, text="Go Back", fg='#E9F1F7', bg='#2A3F54', relief=FLAT)
        self.btn_goBack.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        self.option_frame.configure(bg='#2A3F54')
        self.option_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.option_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.main_frame = Frame(self.student_win, width=880, height=720)
        self.main_result_frame = Frame(self.main_frame)
        self.main_result_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.attempts_frame = Frame(self.main_frame)
        self.attempts_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.test_frame = Frame(self.main_frame)
        lbl_test = Label(self.test_frame, text="In test frame").pack()
        self.test_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.main_frame.grid_propagate(0)
        self.info_frame = Frame(self.student_win, width=200, height=720)
        self.btn_username = Button(self.info_frame, text="Username", relief=FLAT)
        self.btn_username.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.userInfo_frame = Frame(self.info_frame)
        self.info_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.info_frame.grid_propagate(0)



root = Tk()
student_window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And it looks something like this.

[The Student Panel for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys4uD.png)

The whole window is divided into three frames and want to expand each label and button of the left frame(self.option_frame) to fill  it horizontally. I tried doing `sticky=EW` and `sticky=NSEW` but still some space is left. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `self.option_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to make column 0 to use all the available horizontal space.

Answer (score -1):

I was just trying some things and what I have found to be working is to make the label width bigger than than the frame then anchoring the text to the left.